# Simple 2D array throwing exception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

It very strange very why this small code is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
class sum
{
 public static void main(String[] arg)
 {
       int arr[][]=new int[2][3];
       arr[0][0]=4;
       arr[0][1]=2;
       arr[0][2]=5;
       arr[1][0]=5;
       arr[1][1]=2;
       arr[1][2]=6;
       for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
       {
              for (int j=0; j < 3; j++)
              {
              System.out.print(arr[j][i]);
              }
             System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

When I change the sequence like this

> System.out.print(arr[j][i]);

I got the output I expected.

How can I print the sum of the columns?

Comment: have you tried debugging and stepping through your code?

Comment: You're mixing up `i` and `j`... When `j` gets to 2, it tries to print `arr[2][0]` which doesn't exist, because the maximum index for the first part is 1. Switch `i` and `j` in your print statement and it will not throw that exception anymore.

Comment: Thank you for guidance but already mention that I when I switch i and j I got the output but not what I want. I want to print the sum of columns which I am not able to get if I keep [i][j]

Comment: @pinkpantherplease my last comment I actually trying to add the numbers of columns not rows

Comment: By this code I am getting `for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
           {
                  for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
                  {
         System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                       sum=sum+arr[i][j];
                  }
 System.out.print(" "+ sum+" ");
                 System.out.println();
           }` But I want 9 4 11 which is sum of each column

Comment: @user2241865 I have edited the cod in my answer to fit the requirement correctly now

Answer (score 3):

The code that you have given will give ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException . Since in the 3rd iteration of the inner loop you are calling for arr[2][i] (which doesnt exist). If you want a different kind of output you may try

```
 for (int j=0; j < 2; j++)
           {
                  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
                  {
                  System.out.print(arr[j][i]);
                  }
                  System.out.println();
           }
```

For adding the columns , create a local variable sumc and then use this loop

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
       sumc += arr[i][j];
   }
   System.out.println(sumc);
   sumc = 0;
}
```

Comment: @StrawhatLuffyWhat is difference between my code and your code

Comment: Can I add the columns number like this 4+5=9, 2+2=4, 5+6=11, BUT display the sum up values under their respective columns as we do in our addition process in notebook.

Comment: @user2241865 I think this new loop is what u want

Answer (score 2):

> It very strange very why this small code is throwing
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Exceptions don't show any `kindness` though your code is small.

Your array's first dimension's size is upto 2 elements, so indices `0` and `1` exist.Your `j` value is upto `2`, you are applying j on first dimension when `j` goes to `2`, since it's a non-existent index, you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You might have accidentally typed `arr[j][i]` instead of `arr[i][j]`.

**EDIT:** For getting sum of columns

import java.util.Scanner;

```
/**
 * @author Nathan2055
 */

    public class Tester {


     public static void main(String[] arg)
     {
           int arr[][]=new int[2][3];
           int sums[]=new int[3];
           arr[0][0]=4;
           arr[0][1]=2;
           arr[0][2]=5;
           arr[1][0]=5;
           arr[1][1]=2;
           arr[1][2]=6;
           for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
           {
              int sum=0;
                  for (int j=0;j < 3; j++)
                  {
                  System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
                  sum+=arr[i][j];
                  }
                 System.out.println();
                 sums[i]=sum;
           }
           for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                System.out.print(sums[i]+" ");
           }
        }}
```

Comment: It's not an accident I intentionally typed it to get the sum of row

Comment: @user2241865 ok see my edit for what you want

Comment: Mean there is no way to show the output like this  4   2  5 then in 2nd row 5   2   6 and finally in 3rd row   9   4   11 as we used to do in our normal addition

Comment: @user2241865 see my final edit... I have edited it to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access that index of array which is not available.
I edited your code a little and put prints :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int arr[][]=new int[2][3];
   arr[0][0]=4;
   arr[0][1]=2;
   arr[0][2]=5;
   arr[1][0]=5;
   arr[1][1]=2;
   arr[1][2]=6;
   for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
   {
          System.out.println(">>> i = " + i);

          for (int j=0; j < 3; j++)
          {
              System.out.println(">>> j = " + j + "\n");

              System.out.print(arr[j][i] + "\n");
          }
         System.out.println();
   };
}
```

Here is your code output:-

```
>>> i = 0  
>>> j = 0  
4       // [0][0]  
>>> j = 1  
5       // [1][0]  
>>> j = 2  // now here you are trying to access [2][0] which is not available and it    shows the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.
```

Code for adding columns:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int arr[][]=new int[2][3];
  arr[0][0]=4;
  arr[0][1]=2;
  arr[0][2]=5;
  arr[1][0]=5;
  arr[1][1]=2;
  arr[1][2]=6;

  for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
  {
      int sum= 0;
      System.out.println(">>> i = " + i);

      for (int j=0; j < 3; j++)
      {
          System.out.println(">>> j = " + j + "\n");

          System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\n");

          if(i < 1){ 
            sum += arr[i][j] + arr[i+1][j]; //sum of column
            System.out.print("sum >> " + sum + "\n");
          }
      }
     System.out.println();
 };
}
```

Comment: I understood the problem but what is the solution for summing up the columns

Comment: @aminder007 Sorry to say your code is not for summing the columns it is for rows which is easy to do

Comment: sry for late reply i updated your code as per your requirement.